# How can I keep the font color of a row the same after sorting?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I am sorting multiple rows. Each row has multiple cells. Cell B always contains a Leetcode question title. I am doing sorting based on how long it took me to finish the question.

Each question is color-coded based on if it is a graph question, array question, linkedlist question, etc.

I now have a working sorting function in my Google App Script, however the colors of specific problems are not staying the same after the sort occurs.

Any advice?

```
SHEET_NAME = "Problem Tracker";
SORT_DATA_RANGE = "A2:F59";
SORT_ORDER = [
{column: 3, ascending: false},  // 3 = column number, sorting by descending order
{column: 1, ascending: true} // 1 = column number, sort by ascending order 
];

function onEdit(e){
  multiSortColumns();
}

function multiSortColumns(){
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheet = ss.getSheetByName(SHEET_NAME);
  var range = sheet.getRange(SORT_DATA_RANGE);
  range.sort(SORT_ORDER);
  ss.toast('Sort complete.');

  SpreadsheetApp.flush();
  const values = range.getValues().reduce((o, e, i, a) => {
    o[e[2].toString() == "" ? "blanks": "values"].push(e);
    if (i == a.length - 1) o.result = o.blanks.concat(o.values);
    return o;
  }, {blanks: [], values: []});
  
  range.setValues(values.result);
}
```

To sort everything and put empty cells on top, I referred to this post:

[Google Apps Script to sort empty cells in a particular column to the top](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62650982/google-apps-script-to-sort-empty-cells-in-a-particular-column-to-the-top)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do batch operations on font colors also:

[getFontColors()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#getfontcolors)

[setFontColors(colors)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#setfontcolorscolors)

---

You may want to replace `range.sort(SORT_ORDER)` and the `values` part by `range.setValues(o.map(e => e.v))`

```js
function multiSortColumns(){
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheet = ss.getSheetByName(SHEET_NAME);
  var range = sheet.getRange(SORT_DATA_RANGE);
  var v = range.getValues();
  var c = range.getFontColors();
  range.sort(SORT_ORDER);
  ss.toast('Sort complete.');

  SpreadsheetApp.flush();
  const values = range.getValues().reduce((o, e, i, a) => {
    o[e[2].toString() == "" ? "blanks": "values"].push(e);
    if (i == a.length - 1) o.result = o.blanks.concat(o.values);
    return o;
  }, {blanks: [], values: []});
  
  range.setValues(values.result);
  const o = c.map((c, i) => {
    return {'c': c, 'v': v[i]};
  });
  o.sort((a, b) => {
    if (a.v[2] === '' & b.v[2] !== '') { return -1; }
    else if (a.v[2] !== '' & b.v[2] === '') { return 1; }
    else if (a.v[2] > b.v[2]) { return -1; }
    else if (a.v[2] < b.v[2]) { return 1; }
    else { return a.v[0] - b.v[0]; }
  });
  console.log(o);
  const colors = o.map(e => e.c);
  range.setFontColors(colors);
}
```

Comment: The issue is that adding var colors = getFontColors() to the beginning of multiSortColumns() and then setting setFontColors(colors) is preserving the colors of the cells. It is not preserving the colors of the question titles after they are sorted and moved around.

Can you give me any more advice on how to use the two functions you mentioned to get the end result I need?

Thanks

Comment: Added. Please check.

Answer (score 1):

With all due respect to Tanaike, his excellent solution is not for average coders like me. I almost broke my weak brain when I tried to sort out his reduce magic.

So I'd propose the less glorious path:

```
SHEET_NAME = "Problem Tracker";
SORT_DATA_RANGE = "A2:F59";
SORT_ORDER = [
{column: 3, ascending: false},  // 3 = column number, sorting by descending order
{column: 1, ascending: true} // 1 = column number, sort by ascending order 
];

function onEdit(e){
  multiSortColumns();
}

function multiSortColumns(){
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheet = ss.getSheetByName(SHEET_NAME);
  var range = sheet.getRange(SORT_DATA_RANGE);

  // get the column with empty cells
  var range_with_empty_cells = ss.getRange("C2:C59");

  // change the empty cells with '_' or with something that will be sorted correctly
  range_with_empty_cells.createTextFinder('^$')
    .useRegularExpression(true).replaceAllWith('_');

  // sort everything as usual
  range.sort(SORT_ORDER);

  // change the '_' back by '' in that column
  range_with_empty_cells.createTextFinder('^_$')
    .useRegularExpression(true).replaceAllWith('');

  ss.toast('Sort complete.');
  return;
}
```

I haven't tried this on your real date, since you didn't provide the one (and I'm too lazy). But I hope it will work. At the very least this solution is simple enough for anyone to correct and use.

Comment: Btw, this 'lazy' solution will keep all formatting of sorted cells. Not just font colors, but **bolds**, *italics*, any styles (partially applied included), background colors, text align, comments, etc. So it's much more powerful than accepted one.